# Review Pane Opens Whenever I run a Macro in Word

Tags: vba, ms-word

When I run Word macros I've created (which are in the form of comments within a comment bubble), the reviewing pane keeps opening on me.

I teach, and review student work in the form of Word docs.  So, to give feedback, I have a lot of comments I give repetitively, so having a set of "common comments" macros is helpful to me.

I can create the macros, no problem, BUT every time I run one, the reviewing pane opens, too. I don't want that to happen.  Is there any way to make it stop?

Answer (score 0):

You can open and close the review pane using the following code:

**Open Review Pane:**

```
ActiveWindow.View.SplitSpecial = wdPaneRevisionsVert
```

**Close Review Pane:**

```
ActiveWindow.View.SplitSpecial = wdPaneNone
```

So adding the previous line at the and of your macro should probably do the trick.